# How to handle a ear deployment which copies files under the application servers bootstrap folder

Tags: deployment, jboss, shared-libraries, jboss5.x

Our database drivers are usually copied under `<jboss.home>\common\lib` folder in JBoss 5.1 and this is quite annoying since if you have to upgrade the driver you will have to re-start the JBoss 5.1 server. How does everyone else handle such situations in a production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading database drivers is *not* something you want to do on a running server. Your connection pools will all be using the "old" driver - there's no sensible way to make that switch without a restart.

If downtime is important to you, then you should be using more than one server in a cluster, and perform rolling upgrades/restarts on each one.